# Oracle. Memory usage of object instances

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

For example i have following code:

```
CREATE TYPE t_object IS OBJECT (field1 NUMBER
                               ,field2 VARCHAR2(10));
/
DECLARE
  v_object t_object;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. 3000000 LOOP
    v_object := NEW t_object(i, to_char(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

If i understood correctly, on each iteration, oracle creates new instance of object. But how oracle allocates memory for each of created instance? Where oracle stores these instances (PGA?) ? And when it cleans memory?

Comment: In this case the object is created and destroyed immediately because it's not used outside FOR scope, there is no need to allocate memory for more than one instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PL/SQL variables are allocated in PGA because each executed instance has its own set of values. The objects in PL/SQL have well defined scope so they are destroyed when the scope is left, local variables when leaving function/procedure, global variables when their session is terminated. You can monitor the process' PL/SQL memory using

```
SELECT
    PROGRAM,
    SPID,
    ROUND(ALLOCATED / 1048576, 1) ALLOCATED,
    ROUND(USED / 1048576, 1) USED,
    ROUND(MAX_ALLOCATED / 1048576, 1) MAX_ALLOCATED
FROM
    V$PROCESS P,
    V$PROCESS_MEMORY PM
WHERE
    P.PID = PM.PID
    AND BACKGROUND IS NULL
    AND CATEGORY = 'PL/SQL'
    AND ADDR = (SELECT PADDR FROM V$SESSION WHERE SID = :SID)
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you advice me in another case. If my function returns instance of object, and i use this function in view, which produce 300k rows, will it be 300k instances in PGA until whole view selected, or after each fetch, instance, which was produced by function will be destroyed?

Comment: How much memory do you allocate for each instance? Because 300k instances is not a big number. Are you sure you need custom object types? SQL is quite powerful instrument, in many cases using of PL/SQL is not needed at all. It's just because mostly used languages are procedural so people tend to use the approach they know for database tasks too. It always depends what do you want achieve.

Comment: I'm sure, that i don't need to use object types in SQL, but i just have such API from other guys, which returns object type (just 3 varchar2 columns) – and i wish to know more about performance of such approach. I know that 300k is not such big number, but just curious, in this case, will it be 300k instances in memory?

Comment: Regarding the performance, missusing PL/SQL is usually just waste, because of context switching. 300k rows => 600k context switches. As I said it's very small number so aggregated CPU time will be not that high but it's just waste. The amout of allocated memory at some point of time depends on the buffer used for row data. When you read a cursor you specify buffer size. In PL/SQL it's by default 100 rows from C# 128 kB for instance. So Oracle doesn't need to keep more allocated instances at a point in time than fits the buffer.